# Highlight Duplicate Values In a Column For Previous x Rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

so the task is that I need to highlight or scan for duplicate values in a column BUT for the last say 5 rows, eg if I have the data

```
1. 1
2. 5
3. 7
4. 2
5. 2
6. 3
7. 4
8. 2
9. 3
```

so in the end, only 5th,6th,8th and 9th row should be highlighted. I can easily do this using the script over here

```
function myFunction() {
  // List the columns you want to check by number (A = 1)
  var CHECK_COLUMNS = [1];

  // Get the active sheet and info about it
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var numRows = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  var numCols = sourceSheet.getLastColumn();

  // Create the temporary working sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var newSheet = ss.insertSheet("FindDupess");

  // Copy the desired rows to the FindDupes sheet
  for (var i = 0; i < CHECK_COLUMNS.length; i++) {
    var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,CHECK_COLUMNS[i],numRows);
    var nextCol = newSheet.getLastColumn() + 1;
    sourceRange.copyTo(newSheet.getRange(1,nextCol,numRows));
  }

  // Find duplicates in the FindDupes sheet and color them in the main sheet
  var dupes = false;
  var data = newSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  data.length;
  for (i = data.length-1; i > data.length-4; i--) {
    for (j = i-1; j > data.length-6; j--) {
      if  (data[i].join() == data[j].join()) {
        i;
        j;
        dupes = true;
        sourceSheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,numCols).setBackground("red");
        sourceSheet.getRange(j+1,1,1,numCols).setBackground("red");
      }
    }
  }

  // Remove the FindDupes temporary sheet
  ss.deleteSheet(newSheet);

  // Alert the user with the results
  if (dupes) {
    Browser.msgBox("Possible duplicate(s) found and colored red.");
  } else {
    Browser.msgBox("No duplicates found.");
  }
};
```

Now, what I want to do is that when I add a new row I want the code/formula to run again automatically and select the "now previous 5 rows". Like if I add another row

```
1. 1
2. 5
3. 7
4. 2
5. 2
6. 3
7. 4
8. 2
9. 3
10. 3
```

It should now highlight 6th,9th and 10th row. Hopefully, I have made it clear.

P.S I also used this formula

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A:A)>COUNT(A:A)-5+1)))
```

But first, it doesn't highlight the rows secondly it doesn't return the duplicate values but all the unique values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can resolve it without script with just two CF rules:

- white background: `=SUBTOTAL(3,$A$1:$A1)<=COUNTA(A:A)-5`
- red background: `=COUNTIF(QUERY(A:A,"limit 5 offset "&(COUNT(A:A)-5)),A1)>1`

[image: 0]

Comment: if possible can you explain these two formulas as well?

Comment: @hyeri sure! The 2nd formula will kinda take/isolate last 5 rows from a range and perform finding of duplicates. if duplicates are found in last 5 cells then it colors them, but a downside is that it will color all duplicates not just in those last 5 cells, therefore you need a 1st formula which will correct this behaviour by taking/isolating everything in A column minus last 5 cells. and because CF is priority based then the white background is superior because it's first and red color CF rule colors only what's left (eg last 5 cells)

Comment: hI thanks for the explaination, one last question is that can I add the cut off value that is 5 automatically/dynamically instead of manually updating it? For example I'm using count formula to calculate the range but count with in count doesn't work of course

Comment: In the first formula I just replaced 5 with my count formula so it worked

Comment: you mean like changing 5 to a cell reference which contains value 5?

Comment: No, this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55040000/how-to-dynamically-increase-or-decrease-limit-value-in-query-of-google-sheet                                              I have asked another question related to this

Comment: `"limit "&A1&" offset "&A1` is the valid syntax