# How to dynamically increase or decrease limit value in Query of Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

So my task is to get last x rows based on some count calculation and for that, I'm using limit offset in a query. To elaborate more, I have this formula that works fine

```
=COUNTIF(QUERY(A:A,"limit 5 offset "&(COUNT(A:A)-5),A1)>1
```

The problem here is that I don't want to "Hardcode" that value of "5" since my range changes based on the count of some timestamp function I'm using on another column. SO I made some changes in above formula by adding another count function that checks the other column and changes range each time.

```
=COUNTIF(QUERY(A:A,"limit COUNT(FILTER(D:D,D:D>NOW()-6/24)) offset "&(COUNT(A:A)-COUNT(FILTER(D:D,D:D>NOW()-6/24)))),A1)>1
```

The main issue in this formula is this line

```
"limit COUNT(FILTER(D:D,D:D>NOW()-6/24)) offset "
```

as I can't use count function in limit+offset apparently. How can I change the syntax to run limit, offset query?

Edit: This doesn't work as well

```
"limit"+COUNT(FILTER(D:D,D:D>NOW()-6/24))+"offset"
```

Comment: For starters you'll need a space in the string after limit, i.e. `"limit "` not `"limit"`

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=COUNTIF(QUERY(A:A,
 "limit "&COUNT(FILTER(D:D,D:D>NOW()-6/24))&" 
  offset "&(COUNT(A:A)-COUNT(FILTER(D:D,D:D>NOW()-6/24)))),A1)>1
```

Comment: It's better to add some explanations to your answers. You have quite a few answers went into [Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) queue.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the cell reference with the rest of the query string like this

```
=QUERY(data, "SELECT * LIMIT "&A1, 1)
```